# Why does using "while(amount >= 0)" cause an infinite while-loop?

Tags: java, debugging, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm working on a class that's just supposed to take a whole number and break it down as if it were change such as quarters, nickels, and dimes.

If I have it the ideal way I want it, which is to have it continue counting the different coins while subtracting the value of the coins from the amount until the amount is at zero which SHOULD end the loop. But for some reason I'm experiencing an infinite loop.

```
while(amount >= 0){
    if(amount >= 25){
        quarters++;
        amount -= 25;
    }else if(amount >= 10){
        dimes++;
        amount -= 10;
    }else if(amount >= 5){
        nickels++;
        amount -= 5;
    }else if(amount >= 1){
        pennies++;
        amount--;
    }
}
```

I even tried having it print the current value of amount at the end of the while loop to see if I could visually see what might be causing the problem. It worked like it was supposed to, it changed amount to zero, but the while loop just wouldn't stop even though it was supposed to.

Now I've discovered that I could avoid whatever this issue is by changing it to `while(amount != 0)` but what I'm wondering is why is `while(amount >= 0)` causing an infinite loop here?

Comment: It's not "unusual". It's a bug in the code; which is quite common. Since you *are* debugging (yay!) then *use a debugger* - inspect what code runs, and what the values are at the relevant expressions/conditionals.

Comment: According to your code, you should be seeing the word `Error` being printed millions of times in your output. If I saw that, the next thing I would do would be to print the value of `amount` to find out what's going on.  This would reveal that `amount` equals `0`, which is a pretty big clue.  The expression `amount >= 0` evaluates to `true` if `amount` is `0` or larger, which means your loop will continue to execute as long as `amount == 0`.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have left the error part in the code, since I really added that in there after I found out I could do while(amount != 0) to solve the problem. But yes, it was the >= that caused the issue. Thank you again everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this,

```
while(amount >= 0){
```

to

```
while(amount > 0){
```

Or it will continue the loop if the amount is 0.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. Of course I'd miss something like that. I was almost certain this problem was first caused when I did have it as while(amount > 0) when I first started writing this so I tried changing it to >= and I guess something worked for awhile and I continued and then the problem came back later I guess. Thanks a lot for this!